# Formatting jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html

The output of my code is giving me, for example, `1919:08:06 13:22:11`. How can I get the date format: `2019-08-16 15:45:22`?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<input placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:mm" id="datetime" size="30">
```

```js
$("#datetime").datetimepicker({
  format: 'yy-m-d h:i:m'
});
```

Comment: Which datetime picker library are you using?

Comment: try with dateFormat : 'yy-m-d h:i:m'

Comment: From here version 2.3.7: https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer for you below

Comment: Thanks, I change to "Y", it worked. Please could you help me with getting correct time? Time here is 14:46 by im getting 02:46.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the XDSoft DateTimePicker. This uses PHP-like syntax for the [`format` string](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#format). As such, to get a 4-digit value for the year use `Y`, not `yy`.

Also I presume `h:i:m` should be `h:i:s`, unless you want to show 'hours:minutes:month`.

```js
$("#datetime").datetimepicker({
  format: 'Y-m-d h:i:s'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:mm" id="datetime" size="30">
```

Comment: Thanks, I change to "Y", it worked. Please could you help me with getting correct time? Time here is 14:46 by im getting 02:46

Comment: That's because you're using `h` for a 12-hour time value. Change that to `H` for a 24-hour value. See this for a guide to the symbols: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php